# MSBuild Call PS Script - Does Nothing

Tags: powershell, msbuild

The issue is that I get no error, but I get a loading screen showing what appears to be PowerShell successfully called, but everything is suspended (no failures, it just lingers with `Windows PowerShell [copyright info]`.  In digging around, I decided to just see if I could get it to write out a warning and it appears that it is setting the execution policy to unrestricted (which is how my system is currently set as well).

I did think that maybe the execution policy wasn't set to unrestricted, so I tried passing in the `-Force` parameter, but got an error about it being invalid.

The PS script:

`Write-Warning "Called successfully.`

The XML code to call it:

```
<Target Name="DoSomething">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <ponyone>FullOne</ponyone>
    <ponytwo>HalfOne</ponytwo>
    <ponytree>LatterExcen</ponytree>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted" />
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe .\Do-Something.ps1 FullOne HalfOne LatterExcen" />
</Target>
```

Confirmed that this is because of the executionpolicy; when I only run the second script, it errors due to scripts being disabled, even though PowerShell shows the execution policy is unrestricted.

Comment: What is your question and wich of the two invokations you show have a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following msbuild project:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0">
    <Target Name="RunPSScript">
        <Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;.\Do-Something.ps1&quot;"/>  
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The PS script is executed as expected, given the following output:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25123.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 5/25/2016 1:43:41 PM.
Project "D:\lab\my.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
RunPSScript:
  powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command ".\Do-Something.ps1"
EXEC : warning : Called successfully. [D:\lab\my.proj]
Done Building Project "D:\lab\my.proj" (default targets).


Build succeeded.

"D:\lab\my.proj" (default target) (1) ->
(RunPSScript target) ->
  EXEC : warning : Called successfully. [D:\lab\my.proj]

    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.36
```

More details [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files).